# Changing code inside an unexecuted if block alters my program

Tags: c++, gdi+

I am making a physics-based where balls (gdi+ ellipses) will collide. There are 4 conditions I need to program to make the collisions work correctly. To do this I'm using if statements.

I noticed when debugging that in some cases, the code inside the if block is NOT executed as if the condition was not met - however - changing the code inside that if block will still alter the way my program works.

I've extensively debugged to ensure this is what's happening. I've also switched up the way I'm writing my if statements to ensure the logic is correct, but the problem persists.

When the game is started, I add a couple of balls to a vector.

```
/**
* Start a new game
*/
void CGame::NewGame()
{

    this->mBalls.clear();

    shared_ptr<CBall> cueBall = make_shared<CBall>(this);
    cueBall->SetX(410.0);
    cueBall->SetY(379.0 - (25 / 2) - 110);
    cueBall->SetVelocityX(0);
    cueBall->SetVelocityY(160.0);
    this->mGameItems.push_back(cueBall);

    shared_ptr<CBall> ball1 = make_shared<CBall>(this);
    ball1->SetX(420.0);
    ball1->SetY(379.0 - (25 / 2));
    this->mGameItems.push_back(ball1);
}
```

They are then drawn on the screen by iterating through the vector CGame.mGameItems and calling a Draw function on each one.

```
/**
* Draw the ball with as a circle
* \param graphics The GDI+ graphics context to draw on
*/
void CBall::Draw(Gdiplus::Graphics* graphics)
{

    SolidBrush colorBrush(Color(255, 1000, 1000, 1000));
    graphics->FillEllipse(&colorBrush, Rect(this->GetX(), this->GetY(), this->diameter, this->diameter));

}
```

The redrawing and updating of the window is done in CChildView::OnPaint.

```
/** This function is called to draw in the window.
*
* This function is called in response to a drawing message
* whenever we need to redraw the window on the screen.
* It is responsible for painting the window.
*/
void CChildView::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC paintDC(this);     // device context for painting
    CDoubleBufferDC dc(&paintDC); // device context for painting
    Graphics graphics(dc.m_hDC);    // Create GDI+ graphics context
    mGame.OnDraw(&graphics);
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here

    // Do not call CWnd::OnPaint() for painting messages

    if (mFirstDraw)
    {
        mFirstDraw = false;
        SetTimer(1, FrameDuration, nullptr);

        /*
         * Initialize the elapsed time system
         */
        LARGE_INTEGER time, freq;
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&time);
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);

        mLastTime = time.QuadPart;
        mTimeFreq = double(freq.QuadPart);
    }

    /*
     * Compute the elapsed time since the last draw
     */
    LARGE_INTEGER time;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&time);
    long long diff = time.QuadPart - mLastTime;
    double elapsed = double(diff) / mTimeFreq;
    mLastTime = time.QuadPart;

    mGame.Update(elapsed);


}
```

To handle collisions of the objects, a function calls a function called Update() on a CGame object which uses the following code to check if a collision happened.

```
/** Handle updates for animation
* \param elapsed The time since the last update
*/
void CGame::Update(double elapsed)
{

    // Collisions of balls
    for (shared_ptr<CBall> ball1 : this->GetBalls())
    {
        for (shared_ptr<CBall> ball2 : this->GetBalls())
        {

            double centerXBall1 = ball1->GetX() + ball1->GetDiameter() / 2;
            double centerYBall1 = ball1->GetY() + ball1->GetDiameter() / 2;
            double centerXBall2 = ball2->GetX() + ball2->GetDiameter() / 2;
            double centerYBall2 = ball2->GetY() + ball2->GetDiameter() / 2;
            double distance = sqrt((pow((centerXBall2 - centerXBall1), 2) +
                pow((centerYBall2 - centerYBall1), 2)));

            if (ball1 != ball2 && (distance <= ball1->GetDiameter() || distance <= ball2->GetDiameter()))
            {

                // The slope of the line that passes through the center of both
                // balls
                double slopeThroughCenters =
                    (centerYBall2 - centerYBall1) / (centerXBall2 -
                        centerXBall1);
                // The angle between a vertical and the deflection direction of
                // ball 1
                double angleOfVelocity1 = 0.0;
                // The angle between a horizontal line and the deflection 
                // direction of ball 2
                double angleOfVelocity2 = 0.0;
                double complimentaryAngle = atan(slopeThroughCenters);

                if (centerXBall1 > centerXBall2 && centerYBall1 > centerYBall2)
                {

                    angleOfVelocity1 = PI / 2 - complimentaryAngle;
                    angleOfVelocity2 = (PI / 2 - complimentaryAngle) + PI / 2;

                }

                double initialVelocityBall1 = sqrt(pow(ball1->GetVelocityX(), 2) +
                    pow(ball1->GetVelocityY(), 2));
                double initialVelocityBall2 = sqrt(pow(ball2->GetVelocityX(), 2) +
                    pow(ball2->GetVelocityY(), 2));
                double finalVelocityBall1 = ((ball1->GetMass() - ball2->GetMass()) * initialVelocityBall1) /
                    (ball1->GetMass() + ball2->GetMass());
                double finalVelocityBall2 = (2 * ball1->GetMass() * initialVelocityBall1) /
                    (ball1->GetMass() + ball2->GetMass());

                double velocityXBall1 = finalVelocityBall2 * cos(angleOfVelocity1);
                double velocityYBall1 = finalVelocityBall2 * sin(angleOfVelocity1);
                double velocityXBall2 = finalVelocityBall2 * cos(angleOfVelocity2);
                double velocityYBall2 = finalVelocityBall2 * sin(angleOfVelocity2);

                ball1->SetVelocityX(velocityXBall1);
                ball1->SetVelocityY(velocityYBall1);
                ball2->SetVelocityX(velocityXBall2);
                ball2->SetVelocityY(velocityYBall2);
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto ball : this->mBalls)
    {
        ball->Update(elapsed);
    }
}
```

When I run the debugger, the if block:

```
                if (centerXBall1 > centerXBall2 && centerYBall1 > centerYBall2)
                {

                    angleOfVelocity1 = PI / 2 - complimentaryAngle;
                    angleOfVelocity2 = PI - complimentaryAngle;

                }
```

Doesn't seem to be executed, however, if I change the variable's values, for example,

```
angleOfVelocity1 = PI;
angleOfVelocity2 = PI;
```

My program actually changes according to the values of those variables. How is this possible if the debugger shows that the if block isn't executed in the first place?

Sorry if my code isn't minimalistic and concise enough, but I did not want to leave out anything important for solving this problem.

Comment: Notice that you have double collision, Ball_A vs Ball_B and Ball_B vs Ball_A.

Comment: It sounds like you have undefined behavior in your code.  Without a [mre] it's hard to tell.  I can say that `shared_ptr<CBall> ball1 = make_shared<CBall>(this);` looks very suspect.

Comment: @NathanOliver, how else would I create a pointer to a CBall object? Also, when debugging, the attributes of ball1 are exactly as I'd expect, so I believe I am viewing a pointer to the correct CBall.

Comment: @Jarod42, if I understand what you're saying, that shouldn't matter. As long as I cover all the cases of a Ball_A hitting Ball_B, I shouldn't have to cover the cases of Ball_B hitting Ball_A - it would be redundant, wouldn't it? But that wouldn't seem to solve the issue of changing variables inside an unexecuted if block changing the behavior of my program.

Comment: @Justin Just store a plain pointer.  The problem with a `shared_ptr` is that when it dies, it calls the destructor of the object it points to.  So, if `this` has a vector of shared pointer and one of them points to the class then when that element is removed from the vector, the class itself will be destroyed, destroying the vector.  You also have where if the class dies, then the vector is destroyed, which destroys the class which is also not what you want to do.

Comment: My remark should indeed be unrelated to your issue, but "double" collision  might create strange/wrong behavior.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ok, maybe I'm unsure of what you mean. Can you elaborate on "double collision"?

Comment: @NathanOliver Could this be the reason for changing values in an unexecuted if block altering the program? Also, I added a little bit more code so it may now be able to be reproduced.

Comment: @Justin It could be.  Undefined behavior can manifest itself very strangely.

Comment: Assuming only 2 balls which collides, you take action for `ball1 = GetBalls()[0]` and `ball2 = GetBalls()[1]`, and then `ball1 = GetBalls()[1]` and `ball2 = GetBalls()[0]`. without for range, it would be `for (int i = 0; i != GetBalls().size(); ++i) { for (int j = i + 1; j != GetBalls().size(); ++j) { /*..*/ }}`

Comment: @Justin If your program contains Undefined Behaviour *anywhere*, then the compiler is free to generate whatever code it likes for all of your program. So *any* behaviour is acceptable. If you want to reason about the behaviour of your program, you must first eliminate *all* UB (and no, the compiler will *not* help you do that).

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you very much, I will look into the UB of my program. However, I have yet to delete anything from the vector of shared pointers. Your advice is just to initialize the balls and regular pointers as opposed to smart pointers?

Comment: @JesperJuhl, I have been programming for a few years and I haven't ever been taught about undefined behavior. Are there certain things I can look for to eliminate UB, or is it harder than that to debug?

Comment: @Justin There are a bunch of examples [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Essentially, you have to be sure to respect all the rules of c++ at all times. The compiler can't protect you completely from this. You just have to be 100% sure that what you are doing is correct and research the exact rules if you aren't 100% certain. It can be hard and this is the biggest drawbacks of c++. Remember that c++ isn't just translated directly to assembly. It expresses a behavior, not machine actions. Even if intuitively something *should* work, it has to agree with the rules of c++.

Comment: Regarding this question, be sure that this isn't a case of debugging an outdated binary or other build related problem. Sometimes, you get in situations where the debugger can get confused. Since the effects of the branch happen and the debugger says the branch doesn't happen, you may be in one of those situation. *Or* it may be that the branch condition is encountered more often than you check. Perhaps you are just checking (for example) the first iteration where the condition is `false`, but at a later iteration (where you might not break) the condition is `true`.

Comment: Another great read on [undefined behavior](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=633).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Wow, I feel like an idiot. It wasn't UB, but you're right - the branch condition is encountered more often than I check. Thank you and everyone else for the help.